# Easily reuse views, controller, layout in a command line interface

Tags: zend-framework, client-server

My Zend application is going to get an command line php script that should email reports. There generation depends on Zend_View, Zend_Layout and is currently already working fine in the web interface.

How can I reuse this whole MVC functionality in the command line?

Should I add a new controller CommandLineController and call this somehow from the commandline?

How can I kick of such a Controller manually, without having a HTTP request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to check out this excelent tutorial for the Zend Framework from the command line:

[Tutorial](http://webfractor.wordpress.com/2008/08/14/using-zend-framework-from-the-command-line/)